# Cannot run FreeBSD terminal in docker container

Tags: docker, terminal, freebsd

I am using a FreeBSD image from dockerhub. After pulling the image, I need to run a container with a terminal to test some commands inside the container.

I am trying this command:

`sudo docker run --rm -it auchida/freebsd ./bin/bash`

And I get the error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: 
\"./bin/bash\": stat ./bin/bash: no such file or directory": unknown
```

Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `bash` binary embedded in the image, located at `/bin/bash` or everywhere else : you can check it by looking at [`base.txz` contents](https://github.com/uchida/docker-freebsd/blob/0d1a9df/base.txz).

You can use `/bin/sh` instead (the default shell, take a look at the [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/uchida/docker-freebsd/blob/0519557/Dockerfile#L5)) :

```
sudo docker run --rm -it auchida/freebsd /bin/sh
```

(`/bin/sh` is optional in the previous command, since it is the default `CMD`).

If you really want `bash`, you must install it.

Note also that [you must be on a FreeBSD host](https://github.com/uchida/docker-freebsd/blob/1267703/README.md#requirements) to be able to run a container with this image.

Comment: It doesn't give error, but it exits immediately from the container. I need to stay inside the container

Comment: Are you on a FreeBSD host?

Comment: No, I am on an ubuntu host

Comment: It can't work then (see the last sentence of my answer) and the link I provided. You must be on a FreeBSD host to be able to run the container with this image.